# Is it possible to disable default /vagrant synced folder?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

According to source code - it's not, but what if I'm wrong?

So the final question: is it possible to run a vagrant VM (virtualbox-driven) without `/vagrant` synced folder?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Yes. In the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
  # ...
end
```

Comment: This also works if I just wanted Vagrant not to wait for the VMware HGFS kernel module to load, which I don't have in my box.

Comment: Pro tip (I just learned this): Put this into `$HOME/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile` to apply it per default. This is documented here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/vagrantfile#load-order